# Getting printer information failed

Tags: printing

I get  (Getting printer information failed) message when trying to print to my (desktop lubuntu 16.04 shared printer) from my (client lubuntu 16.04 laptop). The desktop pc has an HP Deskjet 1050-J410 series printer connected by USB, CUPS & hplip installed but samba has been uninstalled as not using windows. The printer appears in Printer Configuration window automatically, but will not print. hplip is not installed on the client machine. This happens when trying to print from Leafpad, Libreoffice writer & Firefox. when trouble shooting I get run (su -c 'journalctl -u cups.service --since="None" --until="2016-08-11 13:35:24"' > troubleshoot-logs.txt) This displays authentication failure.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Samba or NFS is needed to print to the shared printer. The desktop where printer is attached needs to have samba server enabled as well as password for samba set via sudo smbpasswd -a user

After that the password needs to be set in printer verification dialog on the client machine.

Comment: Sorry but are you saying I need samba on both server & client machines?  How do I set the password in printer verification dialog please.

Comment: So far I have been using  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu which seems to indicate that samba is only needed for windows. Installed samba to desktop, tried to enable & set P/W via sudo smbpasswd -a user. I can not understand how to do this.

Comment: sudo smbpasswd a- yourusername and it will ask for password to be set. Samba works reliably for printer share, the server machine doesn't even need to be logged in for clients to access the printer. Make sure you have the authentication set with yourusername and the samba password you selected in client printer properties.

Comment: sudo smbpasswd a- username brings up options but nothing about setting a password. I still don't no if I need samba on both server & client machines??

Comment: I think I have sorted out setting the password using https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=61606 I have no idea how to set up the authentication on the client. Do I need samba installed on the client & how should I set that up? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: On the client just go to your printer properties and then enter authentication and enter your samba username and password, hit verify button to see if it works, no need for samba on your client.

Comment: When going to printer properties I get a cups error, Transport endpoint is not connected.  After a while the properties open & the only thing about authentication is under policies & operation policy. I select authentication & apply but there is nothing about entering username & P/W

Comment: Your client PC is running Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes both server & client are running lubuntu 16:04 LTS

Comment: I have uninstalled & reinstalled the OS on my server desktop, but after reinstalling samba etc I come back to exactly the same problem. Therefore the problem is most likely something on the laptop?

Comment: I have read https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1133794 but it does not help with my situation. Please help if you can.

Comment: I get exactly the same problem when using a different Lubuntu laptop client. Please help.

Comment: Can you check if system-config-printer and cups is installed?

Comment: System-config-printer-comm & System-config-printer-gnome are installed in Synaptic Package Manager. Not all parts of cups are installed, but most. This applies to both client & server.

Comment: I get this message (lp: Error - unable to access "filename" - No such file or directory) when trying to use lpstat -p -d or lp -d printer filename from terminal.

Comment: If I try & use localhost:631 I am unable to access the printer. I get an error message. (Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (ipps) isn’t associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

    You might need to install other software to open this address).

Comment: Try install webadmin and see if you can add the printer.

Comment: Installed Courier-webadmin with synaptic package manager. No printers displayed in printer config window. Tried to install printer using device URI & find printer. Got this error. There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'client-error-not-possible'. WIFI stopped working, uninstalled webadmin WIFI working again.

Comment: Did you mean webmin & if so how do I install it?

Comment: How do I install webadmin?

Comment: Got it to print at last it was the firewall on the print server. Tried sudo ufw allow 139/tcp
sudo ufw allow 445/tcp
sudo ufw allow 137/udp
sudo ufw allow 138/udp

Comment: Got it to print at last it was the firewall on the print server. Tried sudo ufw allow 139/tcp  sudo ufw allow 445/tcp  sudo ufw allow 137/udp
sudo ufw allow 138/udp    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT   sudo ufw allow 5353/udp  sudo ufw allow mdns  Non of which worked, so I have disabled the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to print at last it was the firewall on the print server. Tried sudo ufw allow 139/tcp  sudo ufw allow 445/tcp  sudo ufw allow 137/udp
sudo ufw allow 138/udp    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT   sudo ufw allow 5353/udp  sudo ufw allow mdns  Non of which worked, so I have disabled the firewall.